# Xcode Framework Modules

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, clang, llvm

I'm having an issue implementing modules for my particular build configuration. I have a bunch of dynamic frameworks that I would like to add module map files to so that they can be naturally imported into Swift without having to use Objective-C Bridging Header files. The issue that I'm having is as follows:

I have multiple modular frameworks:

*Framework.framework (base framework, required by all components)*

*Framework.Component1.framework*

*Framework.Component2.framework*

*... etc*

I would like to be able to write a module map for each framework that uses this dot notation for the module naming (*for backwards compatibility, among other reasons*) but Xcode isn't allowing me to name whole modules with the dot syntax since the dot syntax is reserved for Submodules.

I've tried creating an umbrella framework that contains all of different components and writing a single module map for that, but given that the frameworks are dynamic this necessarily bloats the final binary size if the user isn't using all of the frameworks inside of the umbrella framework.

Are there any solutions that would allow me to use this dot syntax while having separate module map files for each of the frameworks?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Go with the umbrella framework strategy.

Then, for submodules that are "optional" in your umbrella framework (maybe even all or most of them) set the submodule declaration to `explicit`. This means the consumer must import the submodule explicitly in order for it to be loaded. This is what I've done in the past to import a very large C library into Clang's module system and it worked well enough.

The docs are *okay*, but not great. However, they do go over this case pretty well: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html#submodule-declaration